# If I create a new list to perform sort , is it still valid to call it selection sort?

Tags: python, list, sorting, selection-sort

I am learning selection sort. Suppose I have to sort elements of a list in ascending order.We normally follow these steps -:

1- We divide (hypothetically) the list into two groups : sorted and unsorted.

2- Initially the unsorted list is full and sorted list is empty.

3-Then, we find minimum number in unsorted list and start appending it to unsorted list.

4-Thus , after finite number of steps, our sorting is done.

The thing is that we just hypothetically divide the list into two parts and are actually doing operations/manipulations on our original list to sort it.

I want to ask that is it allowed to instead create a separate and new list object as our empty sorted list, and then start transferring (by removing from original and appending to new list)minimum numbers one by one  ; and later assign this to our original list?

Will this be called selection sorting as we are creating a new list ?

I tried to  implement this. To no surprise, it worked. But I want to know that is it okay to do so and still calling it selection sort as we are not doing manipulations I.e. sorting directly into our original list?

Comment: Why do you care what the name of the algorithm is? All real sorting is done with a combination of many algorithms. The name is irrelavent

Comment: "I want to ask that is it allowed ..." - If the restriction (of having to use selection sort to complete the task) comes from your instructor, then only your instructor can tell you whether it's allowed.

Comment: That aside, from the first sentence [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) it reads "selection sort is an **in-place** comparison sorting algorithm", while your implementation is not an in-place one.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki No it does not come from instructor. What I am asking is that if I create a real list,  unlike the hypothetical sorted list in selection sort, is it fine or not.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki So is it wrong to say that it is selection sort? Thanks

Comment: @mousetail So is it wrong to say that it is selection sort? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care if it's ok or not? Who is judging you?

Comment: I don't know if it's "right" or "wrong". In a sense, since it works it's right. But you are changing two fundamental aspects of the usual selection sort: it is _in-place_ and _not stable_, while your algorithm is _not in-place_ and (can easily be made) _stable_, so it's not what people will expect from a selection sort. You may call it "a stable, not in-place, selection sort implementation"

Comment: @mousetail Please tell answer that it's fine to call it selection sort or not. For example, if you had to judge it as a computer scientist, what you would say - selection sort or not ? Thanks

Comment: There is no answer to that question.

Comment: @mousetail Ok. But if you had to choose it between selection sort or not, what you would choose?

Comment: You can't. There is no authority that decides what is selection sort and what isn't. This applies to any algorithm. Depending on the context a wide variety of algorithms could be considered equivalent to selection sort while in other contexts they might not. Your question is meaningless and can't be answered.

Comment: One more thing: Outside of acedima nobody will ever tell you "implement selection sort". They will say something like "I want to sort this partially sorted list of between 10-100 elements most efficiently in a environment where swaps are more expensive than compares" and it will be up to you to decide what algorithm would be the best fit in that situation. You may end up with something like selection sort or some variant but nobody will care what it's called. The only thing that you should care about is if it's the most efficient way to sort this data.

Comment: @mousetail Ok thanks. But I am currently in high school and preparing for exams.

Comment: So you do have a instructor? Ask them

Comment: @mousetail Yes but the exams aren't conducted by our instructors. It is conducted by government.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.